# How can I setup lighting to achieve this look?

Tags: lighting, clothing

I am looking to sell some products and wanted to take nice photos. I really love the way the way these photos look and was wondering how it can be achieved. It looks to me that it might be natural lighting from a large window but my studio does not have direct sunlight coming in. Can this be achieved artificially through different studio lights? Thank you, any help would be greatly appreciated!
[image: white blouse, light looks to be coming from the left side]

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be large indirect lighting... i.e. a large window w/o the sun being directly inline/visible, or with some slight diffusion. You could easily recreate the effect by bouncing a light off a white wall/panel of sufficient size (and from a sufficient distance).